# PDF export automatisation with different data for each document (indesign or acrobat dc)

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, automation, adobe-acrobat, template-design

For creating several identical invoice pdfs, I made a template in Indesign.

How can I export multiple pdfs with different address fields and dates of purchase based on something like .xml .csv or .vcf?

I could also think of exporting the template and do the automatisation in adobe acrobat dc?

Comment: Google or Youtube: InDesign Data Merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Indesign's built in data merge.

When you have everything set up, go to the Data Merge palette, and open the menu from the upper right.

Select "Export to PDF".

For what you are doing, the default settings are probably fine.

Click "Next".

It will open the PDF save options, make sure that you check the box to "Create Separate PDF Files".  That will give you a separate PDF for each record.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat/PDF know the Form Data Format (FDF), and its XML incarnation XFDF.

It is possible to create an FDF which uses the base PDF as a template, and can fill a not limited number of copies, based on the FDF data.

You might look around for "FDF Template", and also find the FDF definition, which should be part of the Acrobat SDK documentation.

It is some time ago that I did solutions based on that, but if you prefer buying over making, feel free to contact me in private.